# Adding custom style format to tinymce editor

Tags: impresspages

I want to add new style format to tinymce editor. One way to do so is to edit 
`Ip/Internal/Core/assets/tinymce/default.js` file:

```
...
style_formats : [
            {title : 'Quote', inline : 'span', classes : 'quote'},
            {title : 'Note', inline : 'span', classes : 'note'},
            {title : 'Button', inline : 'span', classes : 'button'},
            {title : 'My style format', inline : 'span', classes : 'my-style'}
        ],
...
```

But I do not like the idea of changing core files directly. Is there any way to override tinymce configuration?

I'm using Impress pages v.4.0.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at JustifyAlign, TinyMceFileBrowser plugins http://market.impresspages.org/plugins/

They modify default TinyMCE config without touching core files.