# Custom style format in tinymce editor - override in theme?

Tags: impresspages

This is a follow up question to this:

[Adding custom style format to tinymce editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24368297/adding-custom-style-format-to-tinymce-editor/)

@Mangirdas Skripka or other Impresspages people:

In the answer to the above question: Are you suggesting to make an own version (widget/plugin) of the tinymce plugin or can I just override tinymce's default.js in my own `mytheme/override` folder?

Putting edited versions of default.js and Event.php in my theme's override folder does not work, not with any of these locations:

test 1: `mytheme/override/Ip/Internal/Core/assets/tinymce/default.js` and `mytheme/override/Ip/Internal/Core/Level.php`

test 2: `mytheme/override/assets/tinymce/default.js` and `mytheme/override/Level.php`

Can the standard text-plugin (tinymce) be overriden or do I need to make a new plugin/widget?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Override folder is just for view files. JavaScript or other PHP files can't be overriden in override folder.

And dues to JavaScript nature you don't need files to be overriden. JavaScript allows you to override anything at any time. You better go by duplicating one of the existing plugins and adding your own rules.